# Font Rendering Artefacts on OS X

Tags: fonts, pdf, viewers, mac

Ever since I started using OS X, I have noticed strange rendering artefacts when viewing PDFs I create using pdfTeX, XeTeX, or LuaTeX using Preview.app. These artifacts are not always reproducible, but they do appear frequently. Interestingly, I have not observed these artefacts when viewing PDFs that I download from other sources. **When I select the text (e.g. using Command-A or my cursor), these artefacts disappear.** Do you have any idea what might be causing them, and what I can do in order to fix the issue?

I have attached an image that contains several of these rendering artefacts below.

[image]

Comment: What PDF viewer are you referring to?

Comment: @egreg Preview.app --- the default viewer on OS X.

Comment: I'm not experiencing them; I rarely use Preview, preferring Skim, which however is based on the same PDF toolkit as Preview. It may happen that under certain conditions rounding can cancel some pixels or misplace letters, particularly at small magnification.

Comment: This is likely an artifact of Computer/Latin Modern as it has some very thin areas that fit badly on a computer screens pixel grid. Have you tried other pdfs using Computer Modern? It could also be an artifact of TeXs concept of "glue" between paragraphs. This changes vertical spaces and may have an impact on the pixel snapping algorithm of preview.app.

Comment: @TobiasSchula Unfortunately, the problem occurs with other fonts as well. It has something to do with the interaction between TeX and Preview.app.

Comment: Make sure you don't have screen-zooming in effect.

Comment: pdfTeX, _etc._ produce perfectly valid PDF files including the appropriate information to render. As such, and in particular without detailed instructions on reproduction, this looks like a viewer issue which makes it off-topic.